# How to debug japanese texts in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, encoding

Say I want to call my program by doing this

/testGetID/index.php?ID=此原理是在

Say I want to use the content of ID, namely 此原理是在 to databases.

In zend, all I see $_GET['ID'] is just ?????

Comment: You should be using numerics for your database ID's. Text should be present in a URL for organisational, search and SEO purposes only. This will have the nice side effect of solving this particular problem.

Comment: Make sure you have the encodings right. This includes the one for your DB connection and one for HTML that you output. Setting up UTF-8 encoding should be OK, unless UTF-16 is required for Japanese characters. Either way it shouldn't be tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) you should use `urlencode()` on your ID parameter. And `urldecode()` when getting it. 
2) other option (and a good practice) to create so-called slugs for URL representation. In czech language we change the world "překladiště" to "prekladiste" for use in URLs. That solves all the problems you have.

Wiki is a good example of the first approach. (http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C5%99ekladi%C5%A1t%C4%9B)